# Vue.js - Updated or undo pattern with child component

Tags: design-patterns, vue.js, components, edit, cancellation

I have a problem with updating the correct object from a child component.

My setup is as following:
One ul list with most of the data that I want to present or edit.
On one part of the "li", there is a child component to show that part of the data, which is a list of resources connected to that object, and also to handle the push of new resources.

I also want the user to have a button the enable edit mode of the row, and then buttons for Update and Cancel.

The problem I'm facing, is to figure out which object I should edit and then save. What I'm doing now, is trying to copy the data in row into a mutableRow that I'm then using as my model for the input controls, while the actual row data is being shown when the user is not in edit mode. In the update method, I post to the db and updated the row object.

```
ul
  li(v-for="row in rows")
    p(v-if="!row.editing") {{ row.name }}
    input(v-else, v-model="mutableRow.name")
    resources(:row="row")
    button(v-if="!row.editing") Start edit
    template(v-else)
      button Update
      button Cancel
```

Is this the correct way to do it and if so, how should I handle the prop being sent to my child component? I've tried fetching the mutableRow via this.$parent.mutableRow, I've tried switching the "resource(:row="row")" with a v-if and send in mutableRow if in edit mode, but then I end up changing both objects from the component some how.

Is there another pattern I could use here?

Comment: I would make the entire `li` a component, with the `editing` state and editing value being internal to the component. Update would emit an event, cancel would just reset the editing value.

Comment: Could you maybe come with an example because I don't exact understand what you mean. :/
Do you mean that the entire thing should be one component? The problem is that it has many different input fields so there are a lot of methods and template, so I tried to make it into smaller parts.

Comment: Can you show what your data looks like? It is possible that the one component should have smaller components inside it.

Comment: The data looks kinda as following:
{ 
  name: "Test",
  thingy: 4,
  resources: [ 
    {
      title: "Title",
      price: 5000
    }
  ]
}

You mean that the structure should be like this:
  ul
    li(v-for="row in rows")
      row-component(:row="row")

And in the row-component:
  .root-object
    input(v-model="row.name")
    resources-component(:resources="row.resources")

The problem is that I can't find a way to switch the prop for a mutable copy. It would be great to feed the row-component with the real data, and then switch it with a copy to change in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "mutable row" issue you mention is addressed by passing `rows[index]` rather than `row`. In any case, that's what it takes to make `.sync` work.

My example below implements what I suggested in the comments: a single component with its own copy of the data and its own control for editing mode. When you start editing, the prop data is copied to the local data. When you click Update, an event is emitted, and the parent (via `sync`) copies the edited data into the row. If you click cancel, no event is emitted, and editing ends.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rows: [{
      name: "Test",
      thingy: 4,
      resources: [{
        title: "Title",
        price: 5000
      }]
    }]
  },
  components: {
    rowEditor: {
      template: '#row-editor-t',
      props: ['row'],
      data() {
        return {
          editing: false,
          localRow: null
        };
      },
      methods: {
        startEditing() {
          this.editing = true;
          this.localRow = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.row));
        },
        stopEditing() {
          this.editing = false;
        },
        update() {
          this.$emit('update:row', this.localRow);
          this.stopEditing();
        },
        cancel() {
          this.stopEditing();
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="row, index in rows" is="row-editor" :row.sync="rows[index]">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<template id="row-editor-t">
  <li>
    <div v-if="editing">
      <input v-model="localRow.name">
      <div v-for="resource in localRow.resources">
        <input v-model="resource.title"><input v-model="resource.price">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      {{row.name}}
      <div v-for="resource in row.resources">
        {{resource.title}}: {{resource.price}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="editing">
      <button type="button" @click="update">Update</button>
      <button type="button" @click="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    <button v-else @click="startEditing">Start edit</button>
  </li>
</template>

<!--
ul
  li(v-for=" row in rows ")
    p(v-if="!row.editing ") {{ row.name }}
    input(v-else, v-model="mutableRow.name ")
    resources(:row="row ")
    button(v-if="!row.editing ") Start edit
    template(v-else)
      button Update
      button Cancel
-->
```

Comment: Perfect! This solution really helped me to find the problem in my code. I ended up breaking out every row into a component and then only using one component for the whole row, but the biggest problem was still there. I found that "this.mutableRow = Vue.util.extend({}, this.row)" that I was using for copy the object, only made a shallow copy, and that's why I ended up modifying the "resources" array on the original object. Now I'm using jQuery.extend(true, {}, this.row) instead to create a deep copy. Don't know if jQuerys function or the JSON parsing trick is the best, but this works.
Thanks!